# Getting and setting different values for different configurations

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Let's say that I have some variables that can be different for different users. For example:

```
User1: name = "John"
       surName = "Smith"
       nickname = "veryInterestingNickName"
```

What I did right now, I've created class:

```
public class Users {

public Users (string nickname) {
if (nickname == "veryInterestingNickName" )
{
  Name = "John",
  SurName = "Smith",
  NickName = "veryInterestingNickName",
  Email = new MailAddress("johnsmith@gmail.com", "John Smith"),
}
}
public String Name {set;get;}
public String SurName {set;get;}
public String NickName {set;get;}
public MailAddress Email {set;get}
}
```

it is working as expected, however I do not like the idea of hardcoding new Users("veryInterestingNickName");

I was trying to create enum for that JohnSmithEnum, but it does not allow me to set Email = new MailAddress ....

CUrrently the number of users is not supposed to be very but I'm also thinking to store these values in database, but I can not find out the proper way how to read data from there without hardcoding it (it is currently console application that runs automatically by schedule)

Comment: Delete the commas ','. It will fix errors first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused about you wanting to hard code any values into a class. I really don't advise this.

You are putting a method into your constructor. I have extended the idea of your method to pass two strings to compare them. If they compare then you can change the values of the other attributes, or do whatever you want.

```
public class Users {

    public Users(){}

    public void CheckUserNickNames (string nickname, string comparer) {
        if (nickname.ComparesTo(comparer)==0)
        {
            // To do..
            Name = //,
            SurName = //,
            NickName = //,
            Email = //,
        }
    }

    public String Name {set;get;}
    public String SurName {set;get;}
    public String NickName {set;get;}
    public MailAddress Email {set;get}
}
```

I also think your are confusing:

```
Users user = new Users {Name = "John", SurName ="Smith", etc};
```

Comment: this is how I've implemented the code right now ...